# How to host ASP.NET MVC 5.1 application on Google App Engine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-app-engine

Not sure even if its possible. I want to host an application developed in C# ASP.NET MVC 5.1 and MSSQL 2008 back-end on Google App engine.

Please let me know how can I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: You cannot do this. Perhaps you are looking for http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/ or if you can do without MSSQL (use postgresql / mysql) then mono opens up a lot of options

Comment: Look a google compute engine, not appengine

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at the Google App Engine issue ticket for supporting C# language (or really any Microsoft technologies). https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8

It is indeed unsupported to run .NET (even using Mono) on Google App Engine currently. As of this writing the ticket is 'Acknowledged', so it could be supported in the future. But, don't let Google make you think there aren't solutions available. There are other cloud service offerings on the market that do support the Microsoft technologies.

**UPDATE:** As of 2014-11-13, the Google App Engine issue has been marked 'WontFix' and encouraged people to use Managed VMs with Custom Runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

You can host your ASP.NET MVC 5.1 application on Rackspace or an Amazon S3. 
However, that MS-SQL 2008 back-end will be a problem, since it's windows platform-limited. 
Try to migrate to PostGre, if you still can.

You can do the schema-migration automatically, with entity framework or with nHibernate. 
They create your DB schema for you, by taking it from MS-SQL.

You could also open an Ubuntu instance on Azure, but pricing and availability-wise, I wouldn't recommend it (2016 will again be a leap-year; February 29th is traditionally a downtime-time on Azure, because Microsoft hasn't yet fixed a > 4 year old bug with SSL certificates, although they claim they fixed it).